# What does the getMaxSize really returns about a TextArea?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

The TextArea class has a method called `getMaxSize()` which returns an `int` value. I do not understand what does it really express ? Is it the width ( columns ) or the height ( rows ) or something else ?

There is also the `setMaxSize(int maxSize)` method.

So what does the size mean when working with TextArea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setMaxSize` for set the maximum size of the `TextArea`. If you pass 20 means only 20 characters allow on the `TextArea`. And `getMaxSize` returns the maximum size of `TextArea`. That means its return 20. Don't confuse with column or row or somethings else. For more info, look at [TextArea javadoc.](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/TextArea.html#setMaxSize%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the size attribute in `TextArea` means the number of characters that you can be placed within this component.
I think the same is true for the `TextField`.